# "ReferenceError: document is not defined" no querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, html5, node.js

Estou fazendo uns testes aqui e esta dando um erro:

O index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>teste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/teste.js" defer></script>


</head>

<body onload="inicializar();">

    <img src="imagens\mold_tv.png" width="1345px" height="660px">

    <canvas id="canvas" width="760" height="500" onclick="clickOnUI()">
    </canvas>

    <form name="form">
        <input type="text" name="cronometro" id="cron" value="00:00:00" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

O teste.js:

```
(function(){
    let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");//pega o componente canvas

     let jogador = {
        altura: 100,
        largura: 40,
        velocidadeX: 40,
        velocidadeY: 10,
        posX: (canvas.width-100) /2,
        posY(){return(canvas.height-20)+this.velocidadeY}

     }

     console.log(jogador.largura)


})();
```

E quando executo teste.js no node dá o seguinte erro:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")//pega o componente canvas
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at /home/note/Área de Trabalho/jog_tcc/jogo_tcc/scripts/teste.js:2:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/note/Área de Trabalho/jog_tcc/jogo_tcc/scripts/teste.js:18:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Comment: Talvez isto possa lhe ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32126003/1377664

Comment: O seu código não funciona no browser porque tenta encontrar o canvas antes que ele exista no documento. Veja o console do browser, vai ter erros lá. No node ele falha porque `document` é um objeto do DOM, só existe no browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O document é um objeto do DOM que é apenas existente no browser. Para poder rodar esse script vc vai ter que instalar o [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Answer (score -2):

Crie uma condição para que o "document" seja verificado apenas quando for diferente de nulo. Exemplo:

```
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
    let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")

    // Desenvolver a lógica aqui
}
```